# PHP Return result in different group

Tags: php, arrays, range

all

I have a bundle of data like `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10`

then I separate these data into 2 groups which is

```
$groupA = range(1, 5)

$groupB = range(6, 10)
```

For instance, I have `$data = array(1, 4)` and it will return this belong to Group A. Likewise, 
`$data = array(7,8)`, it will return to me Group B.

So how can I write a script to let `$data = array(1, 4, 6, 7)` return me Group A and Group B?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may want to use [`array_intersect`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php):

```
$groupA = range(1, 5);
$groupB = range(6, 10);
$data = array(1, 4, 6, 7);
$foundGroups = array();
if(array_intersect($data, $groupA))
    $foundGroups[] = 'A';
if(array_intersect($data, $groupB))
    $foundGroups[] = 'B';
print_r($foundGroups);
```

*Note that [an empty array evaluates to `false`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting) while one with at least one element evaluates to `true`.*

*Warning: If you have to work with a lot of groups with many elements you may want to use a manual approach and stop at the first common element found. `array_intersect` finds all the common elements and you don't really need that.*

Comment: clean solution. but not efficient for large arrays. It does full intersection even if checking first value shows that the subarray belongs to larger array.

Comment: @DhruvPathak You are right. A manual approach would be more efficient on larger arrays. Maybe even a sorting of the groups and the data before search begins. But this depends on his scenario. What I posted is a clean solution for relatively small data sets.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```
$data = array(1, 4, 6, 7)
$groupA = array();
$groupB = array();

foreach ((array) $data as $value) {
    if ($value < 6) {
        $groupA[] = $value;
    } else {
        $groupB[] = $value;
    }
}
```

Greetz,

XpertEase

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [array_intersect](http://ru.php.net/array_intersect) with every group... if the intersection in not null it means that some elements are in this group...

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = range(1,9);

$groupA = array_filter($data, "less");
$groupB = array_filter($data, "more");


function less ($v) {
        return $v < 6;
}

function more ($v) {
        return ! less($v);      
}
```

[**See it**](http://www.ideone.com/yi3CE)